# How to programmatically connect a known MIDI Bluetooth device

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, midi

I am able to connect programmatically a known MIDI Bluetooth LE device, but the MIDI device is not in the list, when i use:

```
ItemCount destCount = MIDIGetNumberOfDestinations();
MIDIEndpointRef destMIDI = MIDIGetSource(i);
```

When I manually touch (on the iPhone screen) on the "MIDI device" listed in the Bluetooth manager device list, then it works. What do I wrong? Thanks very much for helping me.

Comment: I have a feeling that your current code only finds unknown Bluetooth devices in range. Try searching known devices too or remove the MIDI device from the known list and see what happens

Comment: Your code is incomplete and does not compile, i. e. because `i` is unknown.

Comment: ItemCount sourceCount = MIDIGetNumberOfSources();
    for (ItemCount i = 0 ; i < sourceCount ; ++i) {
        sourceMIDI = MIDIGetSource(i);
        sourceMIDIlast = sourceMIDI;
        if (sourceMIDI > 0) {
            if (([getDisplayName(sourceMIDI) containsString:"MD-BT01"]) ){
                [arrayForComboBox1 addObject:getDisplayName(sourceMIDI)];
                BTchannelSource[countComboBox1] = i;
                countComboBox1++;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: This is what it does with the manual connection:

Comment: Connecting to peripheral with UUID 447050BF-CFBA-479C-B284-48EE4088BB72 ...
Checking pairing status...
Pairing authentication successful.
Instructing the driver to connect to peripheral with UUID 447050BF-CFBA-479C-B284-48EE4088BB72
Disconnecting from UI for peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x1c4111820, identifier = 447050BF-CFBA-479C-B284-48EE4088BB72, name = MD-BT01         , state = connected>. The driver will manage the connection.

Answer (score 0):

When I use "MIDIGetNumberOfDestinations()" or "MIDIGetSource(i)" before I connect programmatically the Bluetooth device, then the MIDI device never appears in the list, unless I restart the App.

Otherwise I was now able to connect the MIDI device programmatically.